# Filtering Arrays inside JSON object with the HTML string?

Tags: java, json, api

Using the GiantBombApi.

I am retrieving the full list of games available on that website.  The issue I have encountered is that I cannot seem to find out how to filter arrays using the HTML string.

Since games tend to have more than one platform. Doing it this method just doesnt work, I know it shouldnt, however, when i look for answers online I cant find any.  Simply doing this doesnt work

**https://www.giantbomb.com/api/games/?api_key=[mykey]&filter=platforms:xbox%20360&format=json**

Here is what the response looks like in a non-filtered request [json example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnzSP.png)

How would I go about making it so that when I type "Xbox 360", it will only bring back games that are on that platform?

Answer (score 0):

Transform JSON into java object, you may use jackson.databind.ObjectMapper or something similar, then something like this:

```
String platformName = "xbox"
  List<Game> games = mapper.readValue(...)
  List<Game> out = games.stream().filter(game -> {

  for(Platform platform : game) {
    if(platformName.equals(platform.getName()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you get response as XML string, use xml object mapper, if as json, use json object mapper.

Comment: thanks for the response but I need it to be done through the html due to the fact I am working with large amounts of data and I need to be as efficient as possible.  But if there is no luck with the HTML part, I'll give in and do it through code.  thanks again!

Comment: I cant understand what does it mean - `I need it to be done through the html`. Html can't process your data, it is markup language.